# Windows 7: Windows Server 2003 not appearing

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, windows-7

I have a SOHO Windows Server 2003 network with three clients, all Windows 7 (upgraded from XP and Vista). The network has been up and running for about a year, with no problems. Since the client upgrades, the server intermittently disappears from the "Network" window listing in Windows Explorer. Sometimes it's there; sometimes it's not.

I can get to the network easily enough by entering "\MyServer" in the address bar--that gives me normal access, just as if I had double-clicked the server icon. And the server shows up when I do an Active Directory search. The server is just missing from the list displayed in the Windows 7 Network window, which suggests to me that the problem is a configuration tweak on the Windows clients. BTW, I have

Any suggestions on what I need to do to get the server to appear consistently in the Windows 7 Network window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I recall correctly, this functionality takes place through the Master Browser service as opposed to AD (which would correspond with your note that searching for the Server in AD or accessing it directly works fine).  I would start by taking a look at the "Troubleshooting the Microsoft Computer Browser Service" KB article here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/188305

Answer (score 0):

Browsing works through Netbios and always worked better w/ WINS installed although in a very small network it may not matter.  Win7 (& Vista) try to use DNS instead of Netbios so it's important that DNS is configured correctly.

On the server, from a cmd prompt:  ipconfig /registerdns

Since you have AD implemented then DCHP & DNS should also be configured on the server: DHCP should be configured to update DNS and have "update DNS" credentials configured.

DHCP s/b disabled on all other network devices, check the router/firewall and any routers that are plugged in for use as an Access Point.

If all of the above is OK, then install/enable WINS service on the server (0xh for the type) and then add the Server IP to the DHCP scope for the WINS Server option.

Reboot the clients, or from a cmd prompt: ipconfig /renew